# remove toggle within mobile breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hoping someone can help with this.

I have a navbar set up similar to the ones we see on GMail, Facebook, etc with the User Avatar button with options like settings, account, logout. I also have the main website navigation inline with the avatar icon.

When the screen is viewed on a mobile device the navbar collapses as it should however i want the avatar toggle button to disappear so the menu appears like:

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Globe</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Favourite</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Settings</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
```

Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Txw/

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`hidden-xs`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) class to the element you want to hide when the navbar is collapsed. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Txw/3/.

**Edit:**
 I edited the fiddle based on your comment, adding another ul with `visible-xs` to achieve what you want. It looks like so now:

```
<!-- Visible when navbar is collapsed -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Visible when navbar isn't collapsed. -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
        <li class="avatar-dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" height="30px" class="img-circle avatar" alt="Avatar">
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Me</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Settings</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I still want the avatar list items (Me, Setting, Edit Profile, Logout) to show when viewed on mobile, just that the user doesn't have to press on the avatar icon as the main navbar and the avatar options are listed in one menu (if that makes sense)

Comment: Hey @JT1, does my updated answer fit your needs now? If so, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden-xs and visible-xs classes to create different menus. To main navigation and avatar navigation menus use hidden-xs, and create another menu for mobile device with visible-xs class. Like this: jsfiddle.net/Z5Txw/2/